# My class object, based on Hash, returns an empty object

Tags: ruby, class, object, hash

I'm learning Ruby.

I have this class

```
class JspfPlaylist < Hash
  def initialize(title=nil,creator=nil,annotation=nil,info=nil,location=nil,identifier=nil,image=nil,date=nil,attribution=[],link=[],meta=[],extension=[],track=[])
    @title =       title
    @creator =     creator
    @annotation =  annotation
    @info =        info
    @location =    location
    @identifier =  identifier
    @image =       image
    @date =        date
    @attribution = attribution
    @link =        link
    @meta =        meta
    @extension =   extension
    @track =       track
  end

end
```

When doing

```
playlist = JspfPlaylist.new
puts playlist
```

I except to get

```
{
  :title =>       nil,
  :creator =>     nil,
  :annotation =>  nil,
  :info =>        nil,
  :location =>    nil,
  :identifier =>  nil,
  :image =>       nil,
  :date =>        nil,
  :attribution => [],
  :link =>        [],
  :meta =>        [],
  :extension =>   [],
  :track =>       []
}
```

while I'm currently getting

```
{}
```

Could someone explain why and how I could get the result I want ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

A `Hash` doesn't store values in instance variables. Instead, you need to use methods available on a `Hash` to store values, for example [`Hash#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Simplified example:

```
class JspfPlaylist < Hash
  def initialize(title=nil)
    self[:title] = title
    # ...
  end
end

JspfPlaylist.new
#=> {:title=>nil}
JspfPlaylist.new('foo')
#=> {:title=>"foo"}
```

Sidenote: IMHO inheriting from `Hash` (or any other core, low-level class) is not a good idea and in general I would call it a code smell. Mostly because your new class will have tons of methods that it will likely not need. At the same time, you override the original initializer and that might break methods defined on `Hash` or have other weird side effects.

When inheriting from `Hash` that basically means the new class is a `Hash` too. In your context you should ask yourself is a `Playlist` a `Hash`? But this, of course, depends on your specific needs.

Instead, I would suggest having a normal class that only uses a hash as an internal data structure (which could be easily and idiomatically exposed with a `to_h` method).

Comment: @Jad Of course! Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed...